# Convert Format Of Date using /

Tags: r, date, sas

Sample data

```
    sasq=c(-5844, 0, 7121)
    d2=as.Date(sasq, '1960-01-01')

>d2
"1944-01-01" "1960-01-01" "1979-07-01"
```

But I try to obtain:

"1/1944" "1/1960" "1/1970"

with just MONTH/YEAR and no lead zeros on month

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. Have you tried using `format()` function? E.g. `format(Sys.time(), format = "%m/%Y")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d2=format(as.Date(sasq, '1960-01-01'),'%e/%Y')
```

Comment: perfecto! how do i remove leading zero for example instead of 01/ to get 1

Comment: @bvowe try `%e`.